# Magnitute and phase, operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, math, phase, equation, 741-opamp

I was solving exercises related to operational amplifiers and I got to a part where I am not sure how I am getting the arg part of the result. Can someone please explain this to me. Thank you very much.

$$|H(j\omega)| = \left|-\frac{j\omega LR_2}{R_1(R_2+j\omega L)}\right| = 
\frac{\omega L\frac{R_2}{R_1}}{\sqrt{R^2_2+(\omega L)^2}}$$

$$\arg\{H(j\omega)\} = -\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{\omega L}{R_2}\right)$$

Comment: I have replaced your image with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (edit may be pending). Please check that I have done so correctly and consider using MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we have:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=-\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}\tag1$$

Using the [principal value of the argument](https://complex-analysis.com/content/principal_argument.html) we know that we can write:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\arg\left(-\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(-1\right)+\arg\left(\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(-1\right)+\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\text{LR}_2\right)-\arg\left(\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\arg\left(-1\right)}_{=\space\pi}+\underbrace{\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\text{LR}_2\right)}_{=\space\frac{\pi}{2}}-\left(\underbrace{\arg\left(\text{R}_1\right)}_{=\space0}+\arg\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(0+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_2}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_2}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{3\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_2}\right)
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

> Which is the same as your answer, because what happens when you add \$2\pi\$ on the right-hand side of your argument equation?